# How to decrease row space in HTML table

Tags: html

It doesn't seem to be a different requirement but just couldn't get it done, here is my html page: http://www.xiexianhui.com/baxjoomla15/index0.html

If you open the page and check the source code, you will see:

```
tr.spaceUnder > td
{
  padding-bottom: -0.5em;
}
```

that's used to control the spacing between rows in table. It works fine if I NEED MORE SPACE but fails to work if I NEED LESS SPACE. How do I decrease the space in my page?

In some case I also need to make the images re-sizable, how do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`padding` cannot be negative.
Set it to be 0, try to add `cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0` to your `<table>` tag, like
`<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>...</table>`
Apply it to each table. Then, apply `margin: 0; padding: 0;` to each table's style.
By the way, I would suggest you to display the `td` tags without images, with 1 pixel border width to fit them exactly as you like. Then, when they are fine, you could add the images.

**If you want each image to fit the cell exactly**,
you need to have their width sum exactly the same for each cell,
because the height/width of a row/column gets the value of the largest element in the row/column, unless you set it by hand.

**UPDATE**
Try to apply next lines to your code:

```
$( "img" ).each( function(){ this.style.padding = 0; this.style.margin = 0; } )
$( "td" ).each( function(){ this.style.padding = 0; this.style.margin = 0; } )
```

That puts us a bit closer to expected result.

Comment: Thanks, it is still not showing correctly, just a little bit less space than before, I have updated the live version so you can take a look yourself.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I see no difference... Have you followed all of the steps I suggested?

Comment: Resizable means: when user open this page from a smaller screen or larger screen, the image's size gets adjustable automatically. An extreme example is if user is using cell phone to view the page/website, that cell phone's screen would be much smaller

Comment: I DID follow your instruction, you can double check from the source code, like I said, only shrinked a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

You have `table` elements within your `td` elements. Instead of having 3 tables you should just have 1.

To remove the default spacing of a table, you should do:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
```

You should remove the tables from your td elements as they seem pointless. Something like this:

```
<table width="780" border="0" align="center" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#000000" id="content" name="content">
  <tr class="spaceUnder">
        <td width="300"><img src="1930.png" width="300" height="130" /></td>
        <td width="150"><img src="1931.png" width="149" height="130" /></td>
        <td width="150"><img src="1930.png" width="149" height="130" /></td>
        <td width="300"><img src="1651.png" width="300" height="130" /></td>
      </tr>

  <tr class="spaceUnder">
    <td width="150"><img src="1931.png" width="149" height="130" /></td>
        <td width="150"><img src="1931.png" width="149" height="130" /></td>
        <td width="300"><img src="1930.png" width="300" height="130" /></td>
        <td width="150"><img src="1931.png" width="149" height="130" /></td>
        <td width="150"><img src="1931.png" width="149" height="130" /></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: No, I have to use two tables inside one table: because as you can see, there are different number of cells in the two rows, putting them in one single table is not working.